# Export all appointments from Outlook 2010, Google Calendar or iCal within timeframe

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, outlook-2010

I just wondered if it is possible to export all events from `iCal`, `MS Outlook 2010` or `Google Calendar` within a given time frame.

Let's say I need to export all appointments from Monday to Friday from 7.30am till 5pm.

Is there any way to do this for one of the given calendars?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) and [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class to get a subset of Outlook items that meet the requirement. You can read more about these methods and find the sample code in the following series of articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Also you may consider using the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Application class. See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.